# Rails having trouble parse json multipart form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, curl, multipart

I'm having a bit of trouble understudying why Rails 3.2.6 is parsing a multipart POST request that contains json.

The 'offending' curl command:

```
curl -i -X POST --silent http://localhost:3000/foo.json --form foo='{"name":"bar"};type=application/json'
```

Rails interprets as:

```
p params[:foo] #=> "{\"name\":\"bar\"}"
```

Note how the value is a string, not a hash (of parsed JSON).

The headers sent by curl seem correct:

```
> POST /foo.json HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.4 (universal-apple-darwin11.0) libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
> Host: localhost:3000
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 208
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------959d0620faa3
```

The multipart's type also seems to be correct:

```
------------------------------959d0620faa3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foo"
Content-Type: application/json

{"name":"bar"}
------------------------------959d0620faa3--
```

Could someone help me understand the best way to get to a place where params[:foo] returns the parsed json hash, as opposed to its string representation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails doesn't parse json parameters by default, you'll have to do it manually.

Comment: Can anyone then elaborate how his curl statement should then read?